# Why drivering value from node editor is not working?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, drivers

I'm trying to get value copied from one cycle material node to another. 
Why it is not working? (in my opinion it should work)?

I'm coping Data Path from one "Value" node:
[image: Set up driver part 1]

and pasting it into single value driver:
[image: Set up driver part 2]

But its not working. . .

Why?

Here's the full video of the set up:
https://youtu.be/8kmS5WF3JOM

Here's the file with my set up:
https://www.pastefile.com/BOyziq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also find this confusing, but this thing is a bit tricky.

**Important information**

I don't know why, but *RNA path* for nodes isn't full when copying. For me, it is not working without adding `node_tree.` before copied data path.

**Easy way**

Add another variable, which defines object data (*Loc/Rot/Scale*). You don't need to add variable to expression, just make sure it is in the list. And better use neutral object or *Empty* to avoid cycle dependecy

**More complicated way**

Delete current driver and add it via *Outliner*. In *Outliner* switch menu to *Data Block* and find object that is using this material, then hit plus sign to expand tree and find material slots -> desired material -> material nodetree -> finally node you want to drive.

In other words, you should go through the whole data tree - from object to desired node's value.

Once you find line with value (for this specific case - *Default Value*), select it and click *Edit* in the header -> *Add Driver*

This is very brief explanation. For more info on Outliner method, watch this [tutorial vid](https://vimeo.com/40389198) (from 19 minute).